# UserControl with Horizontal ListView in vertical ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, mahapps.metro

I want to archive a vertical ListView that contains a UserControl in which i have some infos on the left  and a second ListView that will scroll horizontal.
The problem is that my second listview will not start to scroll. It seems to pick unlimited space.

First of all some more infos about my setup:

My window is arranged via a grid basically just a row on top with text and the first listview in the second row.

The first listview uses a ItemTamplate like the following:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <controls:MyControl />
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Beside that it has a ItemContainerStyle to display a horizontal line between the items:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" 
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListViewItem}}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Separator"
                                   Height="2"
                                   SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                                   Fill="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" />
                        <ContentPresenter />
                     </StackPanel>
               </ControlTemplate>
           </Setter.Value>
       </Setter>
   </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

(trigger that disables the unnecessary first line omitted)

MyControl is a UserControl which is also just a grid first column some text and second column is my second listview.
This one is special because it is horizontal. Since their are various approaches for this from arround the internet i will show the one i ended using with.

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                IsItemsHost="True"
                                IsVirtualizing="True"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

Item template is again a UserControl (at the moment just a TextBlock) and again the separator lines but this time vertically.

The problem is now that the second ListView is not scrollable. Even if i explicit set them to be visible they are disabled (also after resizing window).

My approach solving this was binding MaxWidth of Stackpanel in ListViewItem Template to Actual with of my MetroWindow.

```
MaxWidth="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type metroControls:MetroWindow}}}"
```

But this and some other tries binding different sizes of different items does not work.
Can somebody give a hint to resolve this?

Comment: *The problem is that my second listview will not start to scroll. It seems to pick unlimited space.* Then don't give it unlimited space - set some `Width` constraint on it.

Comment: @Sheridan I tried. Forgot to mention that i had a working version with fixed with at one point. But this is not the goal i want it to be dynamic.

Comment: In order for the `ScrollViewer` to know when to display its `Scrollbar`, it *must* have some `Width` restriction - there's no other way... how else would it know when to display the `Scrollbar`. However, note that I didn't say *fixed* `Width` restriction.

Comment: @Sheridan As you can see from my try binding MaxWidth i also came to this conclusion. But i can't get it to work. I cant figure out to which parent i need to bind and which elements in my layout need the restrictions. I struggle with this for two hole working days and tried endless combinations. But as i have only worked with wpf for about a week my understanding is very limited at this point.